# Visual Studio Code disable auto closing tags

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to prevent auto closing tags, but the following setting doesn't seem to work:

```json
{
    "html.autoClosingTags": false,
}
```

What else must be done to make auto-closing tags go away?

Comment: what is your vscode version? it works fine on 1.16.1

Comment: I'm also running the latest 1.16.1 version, on both my work computer + home computer and this thing occurs at both places

Comment: for me with `true` it auto closes html tags and when set to `false` it just make a suggestion and then just by pressing `ESC` or `Ctrl+Enter` pass it off

Comment: Can anyone tell Microsoft to stop putting unnecessary stupid features in its products ?

Comment: Anyone know a way to disable this for JavaScript/TypeScript? I like it in html but TS generics are infuriating to write with this on

Comment: First you need to check if you have an extension installed, like Auto Closing Tags, which will override any of built-in VS Code settings. Spent some time playing with VS Code settings file before realizing that I have this extension installed and enabled

Answer (score 27):

Just in case anyone looking at this is finding that HTML tags are still being automatically closed inside JSX files. The setting you need is:

```json
{
  "javascript.autoClosingTags": false,
  "typescript.autoClosingTags": false
}
```

Comment: and for typescript tsx files, `"typescript.autoClosingTags": false`

Comment: Thanks this was driving me crazy.

Comment: In my case I needed to remove `"editor.linkedEditing": true`.

Answer (score 23):

Open Visual Studio Code, go to `Preferences -> Settings`

Under the `User Settings` tab, click `Text Editor`, and search for the setting `Auto Closing Tags`. **Uncheck** `HTML: Auto Closing Tags`

[image: Text Editor - Auto Closing Tags setting]

This search results also allow you to disable auto closing for JavaScript and TypeScript, if desired.

Based on Visual Studio Code 1.64.2 for macOS.

Comment: I set mine and it did nothing. Seems like this setting doesn't actually work (for html at least)

Comment: @JoePhillips What are you expecting the **Auto-Closing Brackets** setting to do when editing HTML? I have verified that it auto-closes brackets `[`, curly braces `{`, and parentheses `(` in a HTML file. This setting is not going to prevent a new HTML element from being auto closed (e.g. `<html>` auto-generates `</html>`)

Comment: I misunderstood what the setting does then. I expected it to not create the </html> tag when I put in an <html> tag. Is there a different feature for that? Gets pretty old having to delete the tag every time I type an html tag around existing stuff

Comment: @JoePhillips Add `"html.autoClosingTags": false` to your **settings.json** file.

Comment: You led me to the right answer. You missed it by just a few lines on the Text Editor preferences.  To find, enter `auto closing tags` in the Settings search. Three should come up: HTML: Auto Closing Tags, JavaScript: Auto Closing Tags, and TypeScript: Auto Closing Tags. I think the OP wants HTML: Auto Closing Tags.

Comment: @TARKUS Thanks! My original answer is quite old now and was based on an older version of VSCode. Updated.

Answer (score 12):

For me, the solution was in an extension. I had the `Auto Close Tag` extension installed (who knows when I though that was a good idea) that was overriding the built in autoclose. Disabling the extension fixed it.

Take a look through your enabled extensions and see if there's any that might be adding this behavior.

Answer (score 10):

### Disabling autoclosing for *only* TypeScript generics

To eliminate autoclosing on TS <generic> tags, but leave it on otherwise, install the [**Auto Close Tag**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag) VSCode extension and add the following lines to your JSON user settings:

```json
{
    "auto-close-tag.disableOnLanguage": [
        "typescript",
        "typescriptreact"
    ]
}
```

**Further Reading**: [TypeScript Generics: Adds closing "Tag" to type specifier #17](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-auto-close-tag/issues/17)

Answer (score 7):

The following worked for me:

1. Go to File > Preference > Setting (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>) || For MAC (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>)
2. Extension > HTML
3. And remove tick from the "Auto Closing Tags".

Hope this helps. Cheers :)

Answer (score 5):

You might need to delete the comma after "false" - Visual Studio Code doesn't seem to like commas after the last statement in preferences.

Answer (score 5):

Just ran into this problem and I went to preferences -> settings -> extensions -> HTML -> disable autoclosing of HTML tags. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I just looked this one up myself and noticed there was no verified answer. Those saying you have to go to the HTML portion are absolutely correct, if you don't uncheck that checkbox under **HTML: Auto Closing Tags** then you will keep getting the closing tags.