# VS Code - How to disable automatically inserting '>' after '/' in XML

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-code

I often write XML files. So when I type a stand-alone tag (like `<br />`) I automatically type '/' followed by '>'.

But VS Code is automatically inserting a '>' after I typed '/' at the end of a tag. But, because I automatically type '>', it results in `/>>` at the end of the tag. This is of course very annoying.

Is there a way to deactivate this behaviour?

PS: I already tried disabling "Auto Close Tags", but it only deactivated automatically inserting closing tags, after typing '>' (which is actually helpful, so I don't want to deactivate that anyway), the other problem was still there.

Comment: I can't replicate this, but I suggest you look at the `Editor: Auto Closing Brackets` setting.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. It didn’t work though, even if "Auto Closing Brackets" is deactivated, it still does this. I find it interesting, that for you vs code behaves differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that the autocomplete comes from an extension (but I assume, this is a default extension). It's just called "XML" from "Red Hat".

In settings.json I added:

```
"xml.completion.autoCloseTags": false,
```

This deactivated automatic closing tags (which I actually would have kept) but also the ">" after the "/" in an stand-alone tag.

Comment: I actually found this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46463820/visual-studio-code-disable-auto-closing-tags. This is HTML not XML, but the solution was basically the same.